# "raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")"

Tags: python

Below is the code I'm using. The purpose is to read an excel file that has over 11,000 unique URLs  each in its own row and on it own line. Program needs to go to each URL and extract data from each webpage. I am getting the following error,

```
raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-directory/police-departments/hobbs-police-hobbs-NM-f54dfdffe164aee1/']"
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # pip install beautifulsoup4
import requests                # pip install requests
import csv
import pandas as pd


def get_urls_from_excel_file():
    # Actually load from excel here
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\URL List (version 1).xlsx', header=None)
    print(df)
    return (df.values.tolist())
    
def main():
    urls = get_urls_from_excel_file()
    with open(r"C:\output.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for url in urls:
            print(f"Fetching URL: {url}")
            resp = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
            dl = soup.select(".Article-block .DefList")
            descs = soup.select(".Article-block .DefList .DefList-description")
            def t(n): return descs[n].text
            addr1 = t(1)
            city = t(2)
            state = t(3)
            zipcode = t(4)
            writer.writerow([addr1, city, state, zipcode])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not really sure to try at this point. The code was written for me as I am very inexperienced and have been attempting to make small changes to get it to work.

It appears it is properly building a list of URL. But having a hard time opening the urls.

I know the second section will work, as I have put a known URL in place of df.values.tolist in the first section, and the program properly exported the desired information from the prescribed url. So the program seems to breaking down when attempting to open the urls put into a list from the excel file.

Update:
Small revision to code based on comment:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # pip install beautifulsoup4
import requests                # pip install requests
import csv
import pandas as pd


def get_urls_from_excel_file():
    # Actually load from excel here
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Douglas\Documents\Python Resources\PO Detachment Project\URL List (version 1).xlsx', header=None)
    print(df)
    str(df)
    return [df]
    
def main():
    urls = get_urls_from_excel_file()
    with open(r"C:\Users\Douglas\Documents\output.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for url in urls:
            print(f"Fetching URL: {url}")
            resp = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
            dl = soup.select(".Article-block .DefList")
            descs = soup.select(".Article-block .DefList .DefList-description")
            def t(n): return descs[n].text
            addr1 = t(1)
            city = t(2)
            state = t(3)
            zipcode = t(4)
            writer.writerow([addr1, city, state, zipcode])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the output from the terminal.

```
>>> %Run 'PO Detachment'"'"'s.py'
                                                       0
0      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
1      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
2      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
3      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
4      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
...                                                  ...
11836  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11837  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11838  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11839  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11840  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...

[11841 rows x 1 columns]
Fetching URL:                                                        0
0      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
1      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
2      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
3      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
4      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
...                                                  ...
11836  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11837  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11838  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11839  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...
11840  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...

[11841 rows x 1 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\Documents\Python Resources\PO Detachment Project\PO Detachment's.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\Documents\Python Resources\PO Detachment Project\PO Detachment's.py", line 20, in main
    resp = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 695, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0\n0      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n1      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n2      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n3      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n4      https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n...                                                  ...\n11836  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n11837  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n11838  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n11839  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n11840  https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-direct...\n\n[11841 rows x 1 columns]'
>>>
```

Comment: When printing the URL you should see the problem. (It's a list and should be a string.)

Comment: you'll have to excuse my ignorance in advance. To clarify, you are saying that instead of creating a list I need to create a string?

Comment: raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.police1.com/law-enforcement-directory/police-departments/hobbs-police-hobbs-NM-f54dfdffe164aee1/']"

Comment: The CSV reader read a line as a list since it could contain multiple fields. You have to extract the first field before using it with `requests.get()`.

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to show me an example. I tried adding str(urls) above the print and request functions

Comment: I believe the problem is `return [df]`.  You just need `return df`.  When you do `for url in urls:`, you have a list of dataframes, so that assigns the entire dataframe to `url`, and that's a datatype `requests` doesn't handle.

Comment: when I try that I get this error:
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '0': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://0?